# JQuery to Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have following html and jquery code. Here what I am doing, when click on any UL item, then its related li has dynamically set at their position with following jquery code.

Now my requirement is that, I want to use following html in my AngularJS. Where for inside ng-repeat i have to set all following ul with its items for each item in ng-repeat.

So click on ul for any ng-repeat item. i have to set its li dynamically inside angularjs expression or by using controll.
if there is any directive that can help to set this.

**My HTML Code:**

```
 <ul class="navs">
   <li><a href="#" title="A"><span class="ocui posts__icon"></span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" title="B"><span class="ocui posts__icon"></span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" title="C"><span class="ocui posts__icon"></span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" title="D"><span class="ocui posts__icon"></span></a></li>
 </ul>
```

**JQuery - On UL Click**

```
      var ul=$(".navs");
        ul.click(function(e){
            var li=$(this).find('li'),
                i=li.length,
                n=i-1,
                r=140;
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            $(this).parent().find('.posts__overlay').toggleClass('active-overlay');
            if($(this).hasClass('active')){

                for(var a=0;a<i;a++){
                    li.eq(a).css({
                        'transition-delay':""+(50*a)+"ms",
                        '-webkit-transition-delay':""+(50*a)+"ms",
                        'left':(r*Math.cos(90/n*a*(Math.PI/180))-10),
                        'top':(-r*Math.sin(90/n*a*(Math.PI/180))-15)
                    });
                }
            }else{
                li.removeAttr('style');
            }
        });
```

**Solution:**

I have done it, as per following:

```
<ul data-ng-class="{navs:true , 'active': activeUl}" data-ng-click="activeUl = !activeUl">
   <li data-ng-style="activeUl ? { 'transition-delay':'0ms', 'left': '130px', 'top': '-15px' } : {  }"><a href="#" title="Report"><span class="ocui posts__icon"></span></a></li>
   <li data-ng-style="activeUl ? { 'transition-delay':'50ms', 'left': '111.244px', 'top': '-85px' } : {  }"><a href="#" title="Block"><span class="ocui posts__icon"></span></a></li>
   <li data-ng-style="activeUl ? { 'transition-delay':'100ms', 'left': '60px', 'top': '-136.244px' } : {  }"><a href="#" title="Follow"><span class="ocui posts__icon"></span></a></li>
   <li data-ng-style="activeUl ? { 'transition-delay':'150ms', 'left': '-10px', 'top': '-155px' } : {  }"><a href="#" title="Message"><span class="ocui posts__icon"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: sure there are several core directives that could be used...`ng-click`, `ng-class` , `ng-style` . There is also ngAnimate. And you will likely need your own directive as well. What specific problems are you having?

Comment: i am new in angularjs, so if you provide some example for changing the css in runtime, how to write a directive.

Comment: This isn't a code conversion site. You need to make some attempts to do this yourself

Comment: Worst case...you could use what you have in your own directive

Comment: i have added a solution. is that fine? or some efficient way, we can do more?

Comment: Well that's a much better start than not showing any attempt. Is it working? Could also put that into your css and use classes and `ng-class` if that helps

Comment: yes; its working fine, but its look like hard coded.

Comment: Numerous ways to do it. Can be done using `css()` method in directive. --or-- put those transitions into css file --or-- store transitions strings in data array. Play with it until you find something you like

Comment: well, i will do. thankyou for your time and support.

Answer (score 0):

An Angular way to solve this may be done within a combination between [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) and [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) :

```
<li ng-click="makeItJumpOrRollback()" ng-class="{ 'jump': shouldJump }"></li>
```

Then having something like this in your controller :

```
$scope.shouldJump = false;

$scope.makeItJumpOrRollback = function() {
    $scope.shouldJump = !$scope.shouldJump;
}
```

`jump` will be added to your element class only when `shouldJump` is `true`  and removed otherwise, so you just need to set its related CSS somewhere : `.jump { ... }`

More about [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) may be found in this tutorial :

https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass

Comment: You should use `$scope.shouldJump = !$scope.shouldJump` since OP code use toggle.

Comment: You're right @jcubic thanks ! I've been more thinking on a simple example to show how both directive can be combined than rewriting the jQuery code.